# How to get values with Directive & ngModel with Angular 4

Tags: angular, summernote

I've created one directive in angular 2 which is initialising summernote text editor which is working fine but I am not able to get its value it always returns undefined with ngModel

**Directive Code :**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({ selector: '[summernote]' })

export class summernoteDirective {

    @Input() config;

    element:any;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        $(this.element).summernote(this.config);
    }
}
```

**Component Code HTML :**

```
<input type="text" name="PostTitle" [(ngModel)]="PostTitle" 
       class="form-control" placeholder="Post title">
<textarea name="PostContent" [(ngModel)]="PostContent" 
       summernote [config]="options"></textarea>
<button (click)="submitPost(PostTitle,PostContent);" 
        class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">Post</button>
```

**Component ts Code :**

```
submitPost(PostTitle,PostContent)
{
    console.log(PostTitle);
    console.log(PostContent);
}
```

2nd console *PostContent* always returns undefined is there any way to get values on button click with directive

Comment: You can create a plnkr or stackblitz to demonstrate this.

Comment: you need to write your own controlvalueaccessor to synchronize the control value and ngModel

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try this package [ng2 summernote](https://github.com/vrudikov/ng2-alt-summernote)

Comment: yes, its not working and there's 15 issues all are open

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. Why jQuery? Its totally unnecessary, I'm not actually sure if it would even do anything in this context, but it definitely isn't helping anything.

I don't really understand how the directive and the component are related, though. If you're just trying to print / access the PostContent and PostTitle in the component, you shouldn't need a directive at all for that.

Another issue is, to access the variable of an ngModel declaration in the template immediately after its declared, I think you need to use a different notation that uses # to denote a local template variable. This will make it immediately available to adjacent elements.

Try this -

```
<input type="text" name="PostTitle" ngModel #PostTitle="ngModel" 
   class="form-control" placeholder="Post title">
<textarea name="PostContent" #PostContent="ngModel" ngModel
   summernote [config]="options"></textarea>
<button (click)="submitPost(PostTitle,PostContent);" 
    class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">Post</button>
```

Maybe that will help.

And i'm not clear what you're trying to do in your directive, but whatever it is, if you're accessing the injected element Ref, you should probably wait until EDITED (nope you can ngOnInit in directives, use after view init for components as another commenter pointed out, element ref is immediately available in directives)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[summernote]' })

export class summernoteDirective {

    @Input() config;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
         console.log(this.config)  <- should print whatever is being sent as input to config property
    }

    ngOnInit()   // edited this back to ngOnInit(), commenter below is right- you dont have to use ngAfterViewInit to access ElementRef's if they are being injected into a directive. They are available immediately
    {
        let buttonId = this.el.nativeElement.id; // random example

    }
}
```

Injecting elementRef basically gives you access to all the DOM attributes of the textarea object the directive is placed on. It is, more or less, giving you what jQuery would give you if you queried for that textarea element by id. You can access  / set most attributes using this.el.nativeElement.attributeNameHere (although a better option is to use Angular's Renderer2 class for DOM manipulation if necessary, to prevent tight coupling with the browser DOM)
No need for a separate element property or jQuery. Typically, inputs are resolved and available by ngOnInit() time, and DOM attributes / elements are resolved and available by ngAfterViewInit() time.

Comment: `ElementRef` is available in constructor, he uses jquery because summernote uses it

Comment: `#PostContent="ngModel"` why is it here? He only wants to get value not `NgModel` directive

Comment: it does the same thing as [(ngModel)] , but also defines a local template variable called PostContent in the process, which other template elements can access. its just a different notation for using ngModel, it will stlil bind the content of textarea to a variable called PostContent, and vice versa. If you use the banana box notation, you can only access the declared variables in the component, or if you wrap the whole group in an NgForm element, and then you can use the form name to access individual ngModel properties in the template.

Comment: I still don't really see a need for it. By injecting an ElementRef you've essentially already provided what jQuery would give you.  You are correct though about ElementRef, my mistake. You only need to use AfterViewInit in components to access nativeElements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its proper way or not but this one is working for me :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;

@Directive({ 
    selector: '[summernote]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})

export class summernoteDirective {

    @Input() config;

    element:any;
    model:any;

    constructor(el: ElementRef, ngModel: NgModel) {
        this.element = el.nativeElement;
        this.model = ngModel;
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        let that = this;
        $(this.element).summernote(this.config);
        $(this.element).on('summernote.change',function(e){
            that.model.update.emit(e.currentTarget.value);
        });
    }
}
```

I import NgModel and update it when summernote change triggers.